# a decimal without an integer part

Tags: regex

I use the following expression to match a decimal number

```
\d+[.,]?\d+
```

I am trying to make the digits before the decimal separator optional, so I thought the following should do

```
\d+?[.,]?\d+
```

but it did not, can some one please explain why?

as I am trying to make it match any of the following examples

```
    44
    44.44
    44,44
    .44
    ,44
```

Comment: Use * like so: `\d*[.,]?\d+`

Comment: @AKS thanks it works ,feel free to add an answer

Comment: It would be a duplicate one now since @WiktorStribiżew added the same :)

Comment: Actually, if you wish, I can delete mine - I did not see the comment until I hit the post button

Comment: That's alright! You have already done the explaining ;-).

Comment: People think that adding `?` always makes patterns optional, but lazy quantifiers are deceitful... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to make the digits before the decimal separator optiona

Just use `*` quantifier with the first `\d` and set the `?` quantifier to the character class:

```
\d*[.,]?\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nO0dE5/1)

The reason your expression does not work is that `\d+?` requires at least 1 digit to match.

Comment: Just to clarify: the `+` quantifier will always expect at least 1 character to match while `*` will match an empty string. When adding a `?` after `*` or `+` just makes these quantifiers "lazy", meaning that the pattern they modify does not have to be matched *once the minimum occurrenes gets matched*, and all the subsequent patterns are tried then. The lazy subpattern is retried only if the subsequent patterns can't find a match. See [*Quantifier Cheat Sheet*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet) for more details on quantifiers.